# can not execute ns build android

Tags: android, nativescript

when i run ns build android, i got this error

[image]

and runSbg.log is empty

i just want to get debug.apk.

```
my package.json`{
  "name": "pillconsfront",
  "main": "./src/main.ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~15.0.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~15.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.4.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.0.0",
    "@nativescript/android": "8.4.0",
    "@nativescript/preview-cli": "1.0.2",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.4.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.12",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~15.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some node OOM error. You could try:

cmd:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
```

powershell:

```
$env:NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

and run the command again